# HTML5 video and encoding checklist

Tags: html, html5-video

So I did a little searching about the whole issue with **HTML5 video tag** etc. My client doesnt want the videos to be played through FLASH and general youtube. So he wants a custom video player and we should upload the video files to our server.

I have a problem displaying the video in **Google Chrome** why is that? http://www.2kfilms.com/jw_test2.html

In the above link you can see that it displays normally in IE. I found out that the best encoding you should have with HTML5 is: **H.264** **OGG** and **WEBM**

So if I have the 3 different formats will it also play in Chrome?
Even this video here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_video
doesnt play in my Google Chrome, and I find it weird. Its black and I can only hear **Audio**